# need help to understand recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
n = 10
10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 55
```

here's a piece of code to add number starting from n, to every number before it.

```
public static int recursion(int index){
    if (index == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return recursion(index-1) + index;
    }
}
```

sorry for stupid question, but here's what confuse me: when the index is not zero, it calls the recursion function again, with the index substracted by 1, so on until the index is zero. However, it's coded recursion(index-1) + index.

so why the index is not substracted by 1 and added by 10 (or any index number) each time the function is called?  why is it not something like this: (10+ (9+10) + (8+10) + (7+10) +....) ?

Comment: `index` is a local variable for `recursion` function, so it always has the value you have passed into it at the start of the current recursion (recursive call). It's not the `recursion(index-1)` that actually contributes to the final result; it's the ` + index` part (which keeps on decrementing from 10 to 0 as you keep on calling the function). Ultimately it boils down to ((((((((((0+1)+2)+3)+4)+5)+6)+7)+8)+9)+10). (Did I count the brackets correctly? ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to write this sum as

```
sum(10) = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10
```

This will let you see that

```
sum(10) = (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)+10 = sum(9)+10
```

and

```
sum(9) = (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8)+9
```

and so on

In other words

```
sum(i) = sum(i-1) + i;
```

or to be more precise

```
         {0            for i=0
sum(i) = {
         {sum(i-1) + i for i>0
```

BTW each time method is called its variables are separate instances in each method call which means `index` in `recursion(10)` is separate variable than `index` in `recursion(9)`.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate it by hand. Start with `index = 10`:

Index is not zero so we go into the `else`:

```
return recursion(10 - 1) + 10

return recursion(9) + 10
```

Now, `recursion(9)` evaluates to

```
return recursion(9 - 1) + 9

return recursion(8) + 9
```

So, substituting into the above:

```
return recursion(8) + 9 + 10
```

So, carrying on the process

```
return recursion(0) + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10
```

And we know that `recursion(0)` returns `0` so the recursion stops at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
recursion(index-1) + index;
```

For this statement intiallty it will be

```
recursion(10-1) + index;
```

for evaluating that `10-1` will be done ie. `9`
Then in order to find the ans of that statement `recursion(9)` has to be found so the function `recursion` is called again.
so expression becomes

```
recursion(9) + 10;
```

And recursion(9) wil be

```
recursion(9-1) + 9
```

This continues and finally it will be `recursion(0)` which returns `0`.